# Best practice Java for reusable code

Tags: java, static, subclass

I have a simple question and I would like some opinions.

Currently I have a Java application for my diploma thesis which needs upgrading-refactoring...

What is troubling is that I have a lot of code that resides inside various classes and does repetitive  tasks throughout the application.

So I am asking what is the correct way to do it ?....some more info

Currently in the application when a task is needed to performed usually an instance is created.. which I guess is normal and correct but I have also seen that classes are subclassed just to get access to their parent methods..e.g.  a class was subclassed just to get access to a methods that performs Arraylist add....

Currently - mainly because my programming background is VBA - I have used the static way of an auxiliary method so that code is used throughout the application ...but i am not sure if this is the best practice.

As an example was requested

The current situation

```
public class Foo
{
 ArrayList myList= new ArrayList();
 boolean displayMessage = false;

 public void add(String message)
 {
    myList.add(message);
    if(displayMessage)
    System.out.println(message);
}
}
```

And the class that inherits

```
  class JustAnotherClass extends Foo
  {
    ArrayList someList = new ArrayList();
    public void someMethod(String InfoNeededbysomeMethod)   //e.g path of a class
     {
         String objectName = null; 
         Object o; 
      // some code here
      add(objectName +" --> "+ o.getClass().getName()); 

     }
 }
```

There is no connection bettwen Foo and AnotherClass...just AnotherClass getting access to Foo methods

In some other projects I have used the utility class approach...so the question is... which approach is the best?

Comment: Sorry,but opinion-based answers are not suitable for StackOverflow

Comment: When you post this on a discussion forum, be sure to actually add the code you're asking questions about. This is like going to a garage to ask about problems with it without taking your car with you so it can be examined.

Comment: If u are not permitting opinions then delete my question . I trying to find a best way to do things...so i don't believe that code samples will do any good...

Comment: Also on the example of car - garage. I am not saying that the car has a trouble...it is working either way but i am asking what would be the best way to keep it top notch...should i use gasoline with extra octanes or i should use regular gasoline and pour octanes separately....in these case u don't need to bring the car to the garage

Comment: Funnily enough i have seen posts where opinions were shared about best practice e.g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936926/best-ways-to-reuse-java-methods   ...Maybe the word "opinion" is making this question a no go...maybe a forbidden word list should be posted

Comment: About the garage - fair enough. "going to an auto shop to ask about pimping your car without taking the car with you to see what is possible". Better? And yes you need to post your code as you are quite bad at describing it.

Answer (score -1):

There is no simple answer. You need to learn how to write clean code. Read some books such as "Code complete", "clean code", "Pragmatic Programmer" "Refactoring: Improving the design of existing code", and "Refactoring for software design smells".

Comment: it would be great if you could give a solid example based on the code i posted above